# Can we enqueue an element at front of Queue with O(1) time complexity?

Tags: c++

This is my Code to enqueue an element at front of Queue with O(1) time complexity,But concept of using QUEUES get lost in this way??

```
/////////////////ENQUEUE FRONT//////////////
    void enqueue_front(T val){
        if(cur_idx==0){
        data[cur_idx]=val;
        cur_idx++;
        }

        else{
        data[cur_idx]=data[0];
        data[0]=val;
        cur_idx++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You might want a linked list: [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)

Comment: use `std::deque`

Comment: In a queue, you usually enqueue (insert) at the back and dequeue (remove) at the front, like in real-world queues. (The name is not a coincidence.)

Comment: Look up dynamic arrays (eg. from Wikipedia). You can have amortized complexity *O(1)* that way, with very fast indexed lookup.  `std::deque` is example of a diffrent implementation: it has additional guarantees about not invalidating iterators, at the cost of bigger constant factor when accessing element by index (it can't just use direct indexing to array, as the internal structure is more complex, usually based on buckets I believe).

Comment: But what is your question? Answer to title is simple "yes, in several ways with different trade-offs". What does your code have to do with the title?

Comment: @KaenbyouRin Linked list is only suitable for cases where you iterate the list and insert and remove in the middle, and the list has a lot of elements. For other uses cases, such as here, it has much worse CPU overhead. It always has much worse memory overhead. So in practice `std::list` is very rarely a good choice for anything.

Comment: @hyde OP says "queue", not "deque".

Comment: @hyde Linked lists are good if you insert and remove a lot in the same predetermined place(s), which is exactly what happens in a queue. They are not good for iteration and arbitrary modifications.

Comment: @molbdnilo oops, misread what you wrote, sorry

Comment: @molbdnilo if adding and removing at ends only, other data structures (like std::deque or double-ended dynamic array) are a lot better than a linked list, basically saving one memory allocation per item, which is a lot of overhead.

Comment: @hyde hmm, I completely forgot about deque. Yeah, you are correct about this... Actually I believe that std::queue is implemented with std::deque.

Answer (score -1):

I think your else statement is wrong.

You are sending the first element of the queue to the end in order to add an element to the start. 
Explaining this with an analogy:

- There is a line of customers in a shop (aka a queue)
- A new customer enters the shop
- The customer at the head of the queue gets replaced by the new
  customer and gets sent to the back of the queue. not very fair is it?

You will have to move every customer (every element of the queue) one step back and THEN add a new element to the front which will not give you O(1) if you are implementing this with an array.

if you use a linked list it will be possible in O(1) but you will sacrifice random access that comes with arrays.

Hope this helps